# Highcharts - how to access category of multiple axis of the point from tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, rcharts

I have a chart with **two categorized yAxis**,the second one being linked to the first one (with the `linkedTo` option). I'd like to **display the category of a point for both axis in the tooltip** but I am unable to find a way to display it properly. I found a way to display all the categories of the main yAxis but no way to limit the output to only the category of a point, nor a way to display categories of the second axis.

Here is fiddle you can play with if you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/75444q2n/

PS: this code might not be very clean as it was generated from Rcharts (a package for R that make possible to get JS visualizations from R code).

Comment: I think you might have to switch to using a `formatter` instead of the various `format` options. With `formatter` you could use the `y` value to get the corresponding axis categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you should use `tooltip.formatter` function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter).
In your case that would be

```
"formatter": function () {
  return "I'd like to have first yAxis category here<br>" 
    + "<span style=\"font-weight: bold; color:" + this.series.color + "\">"
    + this.series.chart.yAxis[0].categories[this.y] + "</span><br/>"
    + "And second yAxis category here. <br/>"
    + "<span style=\"font-weight: bold; color:" + this.series.color + "\">"
    + this.series.chart.yAxis[1].categories[this.y] + "</span><br/>"
    + "x value: " + this.point.x + "<br/>"
  },
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/75444q2n/3/)

Comment: JSFiddle is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use tooltip.formatter (API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and get y of the point to get corresponding category from category array or from chart directly.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4w89vL75/2/

```
$(function () {
    var cat2 = ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    $('#container').highcharts({
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return 'First: ' + this.series.chart.yAxis[0].categories[this.y] +
                    '<br>Second: ' + cat2[this.y];
            }
        },

        yAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun']
        },{
            linkedTo: 0,
            opposite: true,
            categories: cat2
        }],

        series: [{
            data: [5,3,2,4,3]
        }, {
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [2,2,3,4,5]
        }]
    });
});
```